# Triangulation From Two Points To Find The Coordinates Of The Third

Tags: algorithm, triangulation, azimuth, garmin, multipoint

Seeking guidance on The topic. Must I really create what I'm sure is all ready out there.
I'm simply looking  for a basic program to throw on a garmin that will allow me: to create a way point using a GPS, log azimuth from said point. Travel to new location create way point using a GPS, log azimuth from said point then have gps give me coordinates of the cross thus allowing me to relay location of third point with out actually having to travel to point.

Comment: Do you know how GPS works? Or, can you draw a picture of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need **Intersection of two paths given start points and bearings** section from [this excellent page.](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

I'm not sure that the formatting will remain when copying text here, so I'll insert a picture:

[image]